# Quickly building out a set of elements in query?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to quickly build out a set of elements in jQuery? I know I can `$('<div>').addClass('name');` a ton of times with `.append()` to create something like the example bellow but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

```
<div class="navBox">
    <div class="topLeft"></div>
    <div class="topRight"></div>
    <div class="bottomLeft"></div>
    <div class="bottomRight"></div>
    <div class="hBar">
        <div class="leftTab"></div>
        <div class="rightTab"></div>
        <div class="buttonLeft">
            <div class="leftArrow"></div>
            <div class="leftBar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonRight">
            <div class="rightArrow"></div>
            <div class="rightBar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vBar">
        <div class="topTab"></div>
        <div class="bottomTab"></div>
        <div class="centerTab"></div>
        <div class="buttonTop">
            <div class="topBar"></div>
            <div class="topArrow"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonBottom">
            <div class="bottomArrow"></div>
            <div class="bottomBar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** I know I can brute force create it, I was hoping for something like jQuery building it for me based on a mark up like [Zen-Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) or some such thing. I hoping to not have to include the block of HTML in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if the content is going to be dynamic or not.

**If static**, just put the HTML in a single JS string and append using:

```
$('something').html(allMyHtml);
```

If you prefer to keep the HTML in your HTML file (makes sense), then you can make use of a `<script type="x-myTemplate">` block:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="x-myTemplate">
   <p>All my HTML goes in here</p>
</script>
```

... and then retrieve the HTML using `$('#myTemplate').html()`. Any content placed inside a `<script>` block with an unknown `type` attribute won't be rendered by the browser.

**If dynamic**, you can use the same method as above, but with jQuery's [templating engine](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/).

You may also be interested in the lesser-known shorthand for creating elements in jQuery:

```
$('<p>', {
    class: 'something',
    id: 'Blah',
    text: 'Hello'
});
// Produces: <p class="something" id="Blah">Hello</p>
```

Comment: +1 good answer!  I hadn't heard of some of that before, but I'm sure to explore it now. =)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put your HTML into a JS variable and use the `.html()` function to set some element's innerHTML to the value of the variable.  That should do it all in one fell swoop.

For example:

```
var myHTML = '[put your big HTML block here]';
$('#myElement').html(myHTML);
```

And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to replace the DOM tree inside an element in one go. Not sure if that's what you are looking for. In any case with that much HTML as in your example it's not going to be pretty...

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line stuff in JS is a p.i.t.a, but this is one way.

```
var html = ''+
    '<div class="navBox">'+
        '<div class="topLeft"></div>'+
        '<div class="topRight"></div>'+
        '<div class="bottomLeft"></div>'+
        '<div class="bottomRight"></div>'+
        '<div class="hBar">'+
            '<div class="leftTab"></div>'+
            '<div class="rightTab"></div>'+
            '<div class="buttonLeft">'+
                '<div class="leftArrow"></div>'+
                '<div class="leftBar"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="buttonRight">'+
                '<div class="rightArrow"></div>'+
                '<div class="rightBar"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="vBar">'+
            '<div class="topTab"></div>'+
            '<div class="bottomTab"></div>'+
            '<div class="centerTab"></div>'+
            '<div class="buttonTop">'+
                '<div class="topBar"></div>'+
                '<div class="topArrow"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
            '<div class="buttonBottom">'+
                '<div class="bottomArrow"></div>'+
                '<div class="bottomBar"></div>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>';

console.log($(html));
```

I would much rather (and prefer) placing a hidden div before **</body>** and pulling it in with JS to use as a template.